# Using class file in a different directory

Tags: java

I’m trying to run a simple class that’s making use of a class located in a separate sub folder. It’s compiling fine, however, an exception occurs when being run.

lol.java:

```
public class lol
{
    public static void main(String Args[])
    {
        test();
    }

    public static Input test()
    {
        Input asdf = new Input();
        return asdf;
    }
}
```

Input.java:

```
public class Input
{
    public int x;
}
```

I compiled with the command:

```
javac lol.java HOME/input.java
```

Folder structure after compiling:

```
Test
 |
 |---lol.java
 |---lol.class
 |---HOME
      |
      |---Input.java
      |---Input.class
```

Which compiles without errors; However, I’m not sure how to run it afterwards.

I tried running it with:

```
java lol
```

But now the “Input” class can’t be found because it’s in a separate folder and thus result in the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Input
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Input
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

How would I go about running it while keeping this folder structure?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: **Hint:** Might be two problems with your code: 1. package structure 2. classpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add HOME to your classpath:

On Windows:

```
java -classpath .;HOME lol
```

On everything else:

```
java -classpath .:HOME lol
```